# Searching for multiple values in MySQL column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-in

I am trying to use dbForge to test a few queries. I have a database named (test) and the table is named (crimes). I want to select all rows that have specific values in the (Description) column.

```
SELECT * FROM crimes
WHERE `Description` = ('AGGRAVATED: HANDGUN'), ('ARMED: HANDGUN')
```

This returns error in the syntax:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' ('ARMED: HANDGUN')' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` operator to specify multiple values to match a condition:

```
SELECT * FROM crimes
WHERE `Description` IN ('AGGRAVATED: HANDGUN', 'ARMED: HANDGUN')
```